# Class does not define a no-argument constructor with isMinifyEnabled

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

The provided answers in the duplicates didn't help, as I already provided a public constructor for the class, which I even protected in `proguard-rules.pro`, which still didn't help. That's why I asked a new question on Stack Overflow.

I have a Firebase Realtime database. When I use debug mode everything works fine, but when I started to use `isMinifyEnabled = true`, I started to get this error:
(I'm trying to parse snapshot from Firebase)

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.adisalagic.taskmanagerhelper.objects.FirebaseTask$FirebaseTime does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.

My FirebaseTask class:

```kotlin
@Keep
data class FirebaseTask(
    val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    val name: String = "",
    val start: FirebaseTime = FirebaseTime(),
    val end: FirebaseTime? = null,
    val workDay: Boolean = false
) {
    data class FirebaseTime(
        val nano: Long = 0,
        val second: Long = 0,
        val minute: Long = 0,
        val hour: Long = 0,
    )
}
```

Just in case here is my FirebaseCheckedTask:

```kotlin
@Keep
data class FirebaseCheckedTask(
    val date: String = LocalDate.MIN.toString(),
    val task: FirebaseTask = FirebaseTask(),
    val checked: Boolean = false
)
```

As you can see I do have constructor without arguments. The problem is probably connected with ProGuard, but none of the existing solutions on Stack Overflow helped me.

My ProGuard file:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.google.firebase.database.GenericTypeIndicator { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepclassmembers class com.test.finalapp.Models.** {
      *;
    }
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-repackageclasses


# Firebase  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/4900
-keep public class com.google.firebase.** { *;}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class com.google.firebase.FirebaseException

-keep class * extends com.google.firebase.database.GenericTypeIndicator { *; }
-keepclassmembers public class * extends com.adisalagic.taskmanagerhelper.objects.FirebaseTask {
    <init>(...);
    *;
}
-keepclassmembers public class * extends com.adisalagic.taskmanagerhelper.objects.FirebaseCheckedTask {
    <init>(...);
    *;
}
-keepclassmembers public class * extends com.adisalagic.taskmanagerhelper.objects.FirebaseTask$FirebaseTime{
    <init>(...);
    *;
}
```

Firebase SDK's I use:

```kotlin
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1"))
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx")
```

Here is also build config:

```kotlin
buildTypes {
    debug {
        isMinifyEnabled = true
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
    }
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = true
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: With ProGuard messing with things, you will need to explicitly define the empty constructor and use it with `@Keep` to prevent it being stripped out, as covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50724843/3068190).

Comment: Thank you, kind man. Too bad stackoverflow moderators closed the question and didn't realize that the point of the question was different

Comment: Your question was not closed by a moderator, it was closed by a normal user with a gold badge in [tag:firebase]. Moderators are elected users, and they can be distinguished by the blue diamond after their name.

Comment: The class `FirebaseTime` as shown has no no-arg constructor, it only has a 4-arg constructor.

Comment: It has default values, so has a no-arguments constructor. In class FirebaseTask you can see I using no-argument constructor, otherwise it would not be possible

Comment: As I wrote in question, everything works fine without `isMinifyEnabled`

Comment: A no-arguments constructor would be defined as `constructor()` or `FirebaseTime()` - not a 4 argument constructor with default values for each argument. The reflection mechanism used by the Firebase SDK would not pick up a "4-arguments constructor with defaults" as it is not the same as a "no arguments constructor".

Comment: Regardless, I have reopened the question after it was closed when I linked it to the other answer (as covered by Mark above). A moderator did not have any say in it. It happened because I have 1000+ upvotes for Firebase-related Q&A, so linking the other question had more sway than regular users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was provided by [samthecodingman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3068190/samthecodingman)

You need to explicitly define a constructor with a `@Keep` annotation. You can do this like this:

```kotlin
@Keep
data class FirebaseTask @Keep constructor(
    val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    val name: String = "",
    val start: FirebaseTime = FirebaseTime(),
    val end: FirebaseTime? = null,
    val workDay: Boolean = false
) {
    data class FirebaseTime @Keep constructor(
        val nano: Long = 0,
        val second: Long = 0,
        val minute: Long = 0,
        val hour: Long = 0,
    )
}
```